# Full Text Search with ndb endpoints_proto_datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, endpoints-proto-datastore

I've been using `endpoints_proto_datastore` library to build my endpoints APIs and I am trying to figure out how to return a list of records result that I've retrieved from the search API.

The @query_method seems to require a Query type to return and it'll do the fetch call internally. How would I go about implementing an endpoint method that would handle full-text search? Do I just define a custom protorpc requets Message and response Message and skip the endpoints_proto_datastore library all together?

This is what I tried and got an error that list doesn't have ToMessage attribute.

```
Encountered unexpected error from ProtoRPC method implementation: AttributeError ('list' object has no attribute 'ToMessage')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "google_appengine/lib/protorpc-1.0/protorpc/wsgi/service.py", line 181, in protorpc_service_app
    response = method(instance, request)
  File "google_appengine/lib/endpoints-1.0/endpoints/api_config.py", line 1329, in invoke_remote
    return remote_method(service_instance, request)
  File "google_appengine/lib/protorpc-1.0/protorpc/remote.py", line 412, in invoke_remote_method
    response = method(service_instance, request)
  File "third_party/py/endpoints_proto_datastore/ndb/model.py", line 1416, in EntityToRequestMethod
    response = response.ToMessage(fields=response_fields)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ToMessage'
```

Here's a general view of the code:

```
class MyModel(EndpointsModel):
  SearchSchema = MessageFieldsSchema(('q',))

  _query_string = None

  def QueryStringSet_(self, value):
    self._query_string = value

  @EndpointsAliasProperty(name='q', setter=QueryStringSet_)
  def query_string(self):
    return self._query_string


class MyServices(...):
  @MyModel.method(
      request_fields=MyModel.SearchSchema,
      name='search', path='mymodel/search')
  def SearchMyModel(self, request):
    return MyModel.Search(request.q)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were using Java then the answer would be to use

```
 import com.google.api.server.spi.response.CollectionResponse;
```

In python you need to create [Response Message Classes](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/create_api).